Inline Babel script:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
консоль выдаёт эту ошибку с length. Нигде не могу найти ошибку.
Данные в data.js выглядит так:
const words = [
  {
    id: '1',
    token: 'house',
    word: 'Сasa',
    type: 'word'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    token: 'house',
    url: 'img/photo-card-4.jpg',
    type: 'image'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    token: 'dog',
    word: 'Сane',
    type: 'word'
  }, ...
window.words = words

а это основной код:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pics to word</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <script type="text/babel">

            const container = document.getElementById('root');
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
            root.render(<App words={words}/>)

            function GameHeader({value, max, errorsCount, finishedItems}) {
                return (
                    <>
                        <img src="img/pics-to-words.svg" width="112" height="16" alt="pics to words"/>
                        <Progress value={finishedItems.length} max={words.length}/>
                        <Hearts count={3} value={errorsCount}/>
                    </>
                )
            }

            function Hearts({count = 0, value = 0}) {
                return (
                    <p className="hit-points-indicator">
                        {Array(count).fill(null).map((_, i) => (
                            <span className={i < value ? 'hit=points-used' : 'hit-points-unused'}/>
                        ))}
                    </p>
                )
            }

            function Progress({value, max}) {
                return (
                    <div className="progress-wrapper">
                        <div className="progress" style={{width: `${(max - value) / max * 100}%`}}></div>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            function Grid({words, finishedItems, checkItems}) {
                const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = React.useState([])

                const handleCardClick = (id) => {
                    if (selectedItems.includes(id)) {
                        return
                    }
                    switch (selectedItems.length) {
                        case 0:
                            setSelectedItems([id])
                            break
                        case 1:
                            setSelectedItems((items) => [...items, id])
                            checkItems(selectedItems[0], id)
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                setSelectedItems([])
                            }, 800)
                            break
                        default:
                            setSelectedItems([])
                    }
                }

                const cards = words.map((item) => (
                    <Card
                        key={item.id}
                        item={item}
                        isSelected={selectedItems.includes(item.id)}
                        isFinished={finishedItems.includes(item.id)}
                        isCheking={selectedItems.length === 2}
                        onCardClick={handleCardClick}
                    />
                ))

                return (
                    <ul className="cards">
                        {cards}
                    </ul>
                )
            }

            function Card({item, isSelected, isFinished, onCardClick, isCheking}) {
                const {type, url, word: text, id} = item
                const content = type === 'image'
                    ? <img src={url} width="185" height="100" alt="card"/>
                    : <span>{text}</span>

                const showError = isCheking && isSelected && !isFinished

                const className = `card ${
                    isSelected ? 'selected' : ''
                } ${
                    isFinished ? 'disabled' : ''
                }`

                const handleClick = () => {
                    if (isFinished) {
                        return
                    }
                    onCardClick(id)
                }

                return (
                    <li className={className} onClick={handleClick}>
                        {content}
                    </li>
                )
            }

            const useGame = (words) => {
                const [finishedItems, setFinishedItems] = React.useState([]);
                const [stepsCount, setStepsCount] = React.useState(0);

                const checkItems = (firstItem, secondItem) => {
                    const firstWord = words.find(({id}) => id === firstItem);
                    const secondWord = words.find(({id}) => id === secondItem);

                    if (firstWord && secondWord && firstWord.type === secondWord.type) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (firstWord.token === secondWord.token) {
                        setFinishedItems((items) => [...items, firstItem, secondItem]);
                    }
                    setStepsCount((i) => i + 1);
                };

                const handleReset = () => {
                    setFinishedItems([]);
                    setStepsCount(0);
                };

                const errorsCount = stepsCount - finishedItems.length / 2;
                const lives = 3 - errorsCount;
                const isWin = finishedItems.length === words.length;
                const isGameOver = isWin || lives === 0;

                return (
                    finishedItems,
                    handleReset,
                    checkItems,
                    errorsCount,
                    isGameOver,
                    isWin
                );
            };

            function App({words = []}) {
                const {finishedItems, handleReset, checkItems, errorsCount, isGameOver, isWin} = useGame(words);

                const modalClassName = isWin ? '' : 'modal-box-lose'
                const modalCaption = isWin ? 'Победа' : 'Поражене'
                const modalDescription = `Вы нашли ${finishedItems.length / 2} слова`

                return (
                    <section className="game">
                        <GameHeader value={finishedItems.length} max={words.length} errorsCount={errorsCount} />
                        <Grid words={words} finishedItems={finishedItems} checkItems={checkItems} />
                        {isGameOver && (
                            <Modal
                                className={isWin ? "" : "modal-box-lose"}
                                caption={isWin ? "Победа" : "Поражение"}
                                description={`Вы нашли ${finishedItems.length / 2} слова`}
                                onReset={handleReset}
                            />
                        )}
                    </section>
                );
            }
//root.render(<App words={words} />);
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="vendor/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="settings.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


// return ( ===> перечисление через запятую возвращает только последнее значение, поэтому остаётся только isWin
// а нам нужен объект со всеми значениями, чтобы они были доступны в App
// return { ===> фигурные скобки создают объект, теперь все значения доступны по именам

Там из отступов в коде ещё и непонятно, от какой функции вообще этот return с круглыми скобками :/

Илзия Исхакова, используйте дебаг (F11), чтоб смотреть значения по мере их заполнения, вы сразу заметите, где пробел

@CrazyElf, поправила в редакторе

@Dev18 А, ну вот теперь понятно, и правда видимо ошибка в скобках.

@CrazyElf, я вижу еще 1. опечатку (?) hit=points-used  - это не должно играть роли макс на стиль 2. перед вызовом индекса по-моему лучше добавить проверку checkItems(selectedItems[0], id) 3. //root.render(<App words={words} />); тут не знаю как должно быть, там json точно загружен ?

Обычно браузер указывает на строку, в которой возникла ошибка. Сама ошибка говорит вам, что вы пытаетесь взять свойство length у переменной, которая undefined. Чуть более подробно про ошибку TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
